memory_order_relaxed with c++11/14 in cppreference
I'm confused with this statement on Relaxed ordering

Even with relaxed memory model, out-of-thin-air values are not allowed
to circularly depend on their own computations, for example, with x
and y initially zero,
// Thread 1:
 r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 if (r1 == 42) x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
 // Thread 2:
 r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
 if (r2 == 42) y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed);

is not allowed to produce r1 == r2 ==
42 since the store of 42 to y is only possible if the store to x
stores 42, which circularly depends on the store to y storing 42. Note
that until C++14, this was technically allowed by the specification,
but not recommended for implementors.

I've done a test with the following code, running for about 2 hours, neither r1 == 42 nor r2 == 42 occurs.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> x(0);
std::atomic<int> y(0);
int r1 = 0;
int r2 = 0;

void foo1() {
    r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (r1 == 42) {
        x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}

void foo2() {
    r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (r2 == 42) {
        y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        std::thread t1(foo1);
        std::thread t2(foo2);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        if (r1 == 42 || r2 == 42) {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "r1 " << r1 << ", r2 " << r2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS (WSL2)
G++: 11.4.0
Compile command: g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -pthread
My questions are:
What does 'Note that until C++14, this was technically allowed by the specification, but not recommended for implementors.' means?
Does it means to produce r1 == r2 == 42 with this code is possible with C++11? If so, why is this possible?

It was theoretically allowed by the standard. Most likely, no actual implementation actually produced this outcome. And later the standard was tightened to formally disallow it. Besides, you are likely running your experiments on a x64 CPU which doesn't support relaxed memory ordering; all atomic operations in effect have sequential consistency ordering. You need more exotic hardware to have any chance of actually observing CPU cache incoherence effects.

@IgorTandetnik "all atomic operations in effect have sequential consistency ordering": There is still compiler reordering that can cause a relaxed operation to behave differently than acquire/release would. And x86(-64) only gives you acquire/release for free, not sequential consistency.

The x86 series started as single core processors without any cache. Later models had to keep this coherency to be backwards compatible.


Does it means to produce r1 == r2 == 42 with this code is possible with C++11? If so, why is this possible?

Yes, it is technically allowed. It is possible, because it is allowed. Whether any hardware/implementation would actually be able to produce that outcome is a different question than what the language specification allows.
This is however more of an issue with the specification rather than intended possible behavior. I do not expect that any hardware should actually be able to produce such outcomes.
See e.g. N3710 for a discussion of why it is difficult to write the specification in such a way that out-of-thin-air values are impossible (and N3786 for the reduced wording that made it into C++14).
Cppreference seems to be wrong btw. In C++11 there was an attempt at specification to prohibit out-of-thin-air values, which according to the paper linked above made relaxed atomics practically unimplementable. C++14 replaces that specification with a recommendation to avoid out-of-thin-air values without actually specifying what that means exactly.
A recommendation is just that and a C++ implementation does not need to follow it to be conforming, although it would certainly be against the intent to not follow it.

It's still technically allowed. The standard only says that it "should" not happen, because we don't know how to normatively forbid it. http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#8

@BrianBi Thank you for the correction. I took what is written at cppreference at face value. I hope my answer is now correct.
